# value of list of dictionary is equal to "string" then give result true

Tags: python

```
list1 = [{'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930','type': 'limit','side': 'buy','price': 0.7,'amount': 1.0},{'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930','type': 'limit','side': 'buy','price': 0.75,'amount': 2.0}]
result = list1[0]['side'] == 'buy' or list1[1]['side'] == 'buy'
```

result = True

but problem occur when list1 is updated every 5 second and list of dictionary some time 1 or 0 or 5, so how can get resut = True, if any one of 'side' == 'buy' in list of dictionary.

Comment: You may also want to use a lock to access the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `any`

```
values = [{'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'buy', 'price': 0.7, 'amount': 1.0},
          {'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'buy', 'price': 0.75, 'amount': 2.0}]

result = any(x['side'] == "buy" for x in values)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [{'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'buy', 'price': 0.7, 'amount': 1.0},
         {'symbol': 'EOS/USD:USD-220930', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'buy', 'price': 0.75, 'amount': 2.0}]

result = False
for d in list1:
    if d.get('side') == 'buy':
        result = True
        break

print(result)
```